# how to create endless random numbers

Tags: c, random

I tried to generate infinite random number of range 0-9 using while loop, however my code only manage to generate 1 random number before exiting, why is it and how could I change it? Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    while(1 < 2) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("%d\n", rand() % 9);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what `time(NULL)` returns (and the value it returns if you call it multiple times in a single second), and call `srand` only *once*.

Comment: Also, the code as shown will not exit at all.

Comment: I intend it to not exit until I terminate, but it stopped after it gave the first random number

Comment: So the problem isn't that you only get the same number over and over again, but that your supposedly infinite loop only iterates one time? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Yes, my supposedly infinite loop only iterates one time even after I recompile it several times, but now it suddenly works as intended after I wait for a while to recompile it. thanks for the suggestions on srand tho!

Comment: I recognize that problem, that it seems like the old source file have been cached and it doesn't matter how many times you edit it or recompile it, the program still behaves as it was using old source code. I don't remember if it was on Windows or on Linux, or which environment I used (IDE versus command line), but I remember that I never figured out the problem. It might be worth posting a new question about it (or at the very least try to search for more information first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
while (1 < 2)
```

is of course always true, so the loop will run forever. I tried it, and it works for me at least.

A more concise way of writing an infinite loop is

```
for (;;)
```

or maybe

```
while (true)
```

but the `for` version has fewer magical constants so it can be considered better in some dimension.

Also, don't call `srand()` all the time, that will reset the RNG for each iteration. Just call it once, if you feel you have to, before the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (;;) {
        printf("%d\n", rand() % 10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that I changed it to `% 10`, with `% 9` you only get numbers in the range 0 through 8, inclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on for loop and srand! I dont know why it didn't loop forever before but now it does, which was what I intend to do.